# Filter Multiple Pivot tables By cell value same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

My end goal is to be able to filter multiple pivot tables all in the same worksheet based on a cell value (H3).  Currently i have the code which works perfectly with one pivot table and I'm trying to add the rest. Any recommendations?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'Set the Variables to be used

Dim pt As PivotTable

Dim Field As PivotField

Dim NewCat As String

  'Here you amend to suit your data

Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Customer Name")

NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H3").Value



'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Customer Name")

    .ClearAllFilters

    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, 

Value1:=ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Value

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim NewCat As String

    'if this is in the sheet1 code module you can use
    '  "Me" in place of "Worksheets("Sheet1")"
    NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H3").Value
    Debug.Print "Filtering on '" & NewCat & "'"
    'loop over all pivottables on the sheet
    For Each pt In Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
        With pt.PivotFields("Customer Name")
            .ClearAllFilters
            .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=NewCat
        End With
    Next pt

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim this works great, just what i was looking for!!!